# How to center 2 labels horizontally side by side in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

This is a result I need:

[image]

Width of labels are **not fixed**. They may be equal, first may be larger then second, and the second may be larger than first. I have found some solutions in other questions, but it does not satisfy me, because I do not want to add extra views and my widths are not fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made some research, and it is **still impossible without extra view**:-)

But the simplest way is:

**1. constraints for wrapper:**

[image]

**2. constraints for embedded views:**

[image]
[image]

**3. The result is following:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Heres how to do it programmatically

```
let margins = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
//Let x equal whatever you want your height to be 
//Let y equal whatever you want your width to be 

view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: X).isActive = true
view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Y).isActive = true

view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerXAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.topAnchor).isActive = true
view2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: X).isActive = true
```